# How to setup Canon Pixma MG2120 Scan and Print

Tags: printing, canon, pixma

I looked a few places for this and did not find a real solution. I found a duplicate ticket which was unanswered regarding the scanner and many incorrect threads in various forums stating the scanner can't work. I bought mine today, and it is now working so I am posting. Take this into consideration when moderating.

The USA Canon site does not have any linux drivers. You have to use Japan Or Australia's version of their official site to find what you need.

Scanner:
[MG2100 series ScanGear MP Ver. 1.80 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)](http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100392902.html)

Printer:
[MG2100 series IJ Printer Driver Ver. 3.60 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)](http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/0100392602.html)

Untar and run ./install.sh

Once they are installed you can print as you would normally and scan using their software

```
$ scangearmp
```

xsane and other default scan solutions will fail to recognize the scanner.

Comment: With these package, is it possible to share the printer+scanner with linux and windows systems? Does this works with cups?

Comment: All the AIO printers doesnt need additional drivers for their "main function" in Ubuntu. Install common printer and Scanner drivers mentioned [here](http://www.allfreeubuntu.tk/drivers/). Then use the printer with `system-config-printer-gnome` and scanner with `simple-scan`